# How can I create a WPF style so all Image controls have a MouseDown(click) event on it?

Tags: c#, wpf, styles

Since the Image control doesn't have a Click event, I simulate it using MouseDown event and it works exactly like a Click.

Here's my style:

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="imageStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
        <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ScaleTransform />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value="0.5, 0.5" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Image.MouseEnter">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.5" From="1" To="1.2" AutoReverse="True"
                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX"/>
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2" From="1" To="1.2" AutoReverse="True" 
                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleY"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Where/how can I create a click event so I don't have to do this to EVERY SINGLE IMAGE on my Form:

Comment: I think I could add another <EventTrigger> with the routed event: "Image.MouseDown" Problem is, I don't know what to put inside of those tags.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do... there's no generic answer. Some things can be done with a trigger, others require code...

Comment: Papuccino1: EventTriggers currently only support storyboard and sound player actions, not running arbitrary code; you can't extend TriggerAction because it has internal abstract members.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use an [`EventSetter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.eventsetter.aspx) :

```
<EventSetter Event="MouseClick" Handler="image_Click"/>
```

And in code-behind :

```
private void image_Click(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Image image = sender as Image;
    if (image != null)
    {
        // do something with the image
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for. I knew it was something sleek like this. :3

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `EventSetter` as Thomas describes, or you could simply catch the tunneling `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event at the Window level and check if an Image was clicked.

To use `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` to do something for all Images in your application, just add this to your top level `Window`:

```
protected override void OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  if(e.Source is Image)
  {
    // ... whatever you want to do when an image is clicked ...
  }
}
```